# Rewrite StringJoiner using Java 8 Streams for an ArrayList<Double> input

Tags: java, java-stream

How would I rewrite this using Java 8 streams? I'm not really familiar with Java 8 features yet.

```
private final ArrayList<Double> ledger = new ArrayList<>();

/**
 *
 * @return the ledger as a String (e.g. "1.20|2.50|1.90")
 */
public String getLedgerString() {
    StringJoiner  sj = new StringJoiner("|","[","]");
    for (double d : ledger)
        sj.add(String.format("%.2f", d));
    return sj.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a stringjoiner directly isn't effective when you have all your information already self contained in a streamable list, because you can stream directly and create a string with [`Collectors.joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-).

This can be used like:

```
ledger.stream()
    .map(d->String.format("%.2f", d))
    .collect(
      Collectors.joining("|","[","]")
    );
```

The 3 arguments to the method are the same as you would expect for a `StringJoiner`.

The above code uses `.stream()` to loop over the `List` then `.map()` them to strings, then finally collects them using `Collectors.joining`.

[Yuri Schimke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1542667/yuri-schimke) also suggested another method, you can also use [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to format the numbers. This can be done with:

```
ledger.stream()
    .map(new DecimalFormat("0.00")::format)
    .collect(
      Collectors.joining("|","[","]")
    );
```

It makes the code slightly longer, but has the advantage that you can easily change the decimal separator to something else.

Comment: great, thanks - makes my code look cleaner for sure. Thanks for explaining it as well.

Comment: I'm not sure using `Collectors.joining` is more effective than a `for` loop (maybe if there's a lot of elements) but it is definitely cleaner.

Comment: Another tweak you can use is to use ".map(new DecimalFormat("0.00")::format)" which is probably slightly cheaper than calling the static format method each time. TIOLI.

Comment: Good tip indeed, edited into the answer. I didn't test the performance, but I saw the advantage of it that you can easily change the number grouping.

Comment: "Using a stringjoiner directly isn't effective." Wrong! It's effective as it gets you where you want to go. It's just *more effective* to use `Collectors`.

Comment: @Olivier Grégoire: there is no difference between these two forms. In fact `Collectors.joining` uses `StringJoiner` the same way as the manual loop version does.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example:

```
    private static void joiningTest() {
    List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
    String str = strs.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(":","[","]"));
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

The output would be:

```
[one:two:three]
```